# Why the Broadcast receiver does not work after killing Android app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, recording

I am using a broadcast receiver in my app to record calls. Everything works fine in Android 5.0 emulator device. If I kill the app, it automatically starts recording calls. But the same app when I installed on my device running Android 6.0, it works until the app is running. When I kill the app the recording is not started, the broadcast receiver is not triggered.

Comment: What is the 6.0 device. On some devices swiping off the app does not kills it  but force stops it. Which wont trigger the receiver

Comment: Android 6.0 Marshmallow device.

Comment: Is it by any chance Xiaomi or OPPO

Comment: What is the solution to this? So that it does not force closes the receiver

Comment: Yes Xiaomi Redmi note 4

Comment: I am also using a broadcast receiver to check network, that receiver is working fine, this receiver is also working fine in emulator

Comment: On Xiaomi devices swiping the app executes 'Force stop' on force stop the receiver wont work, im not sure there is anything you can do. This will happen on XIaomi`s MIUI and some other custom ROM

Comment: Yes I just checked another thread that has discussed this problem, I am giving link you can also check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506105/sms-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-receive-sms-after-app-killed-or-device-restart-on

Comment: My question may sound dumb but are you registering your broadcast receiver in the manifest ?

Comment: Yes , in manifest

Comment: Please accept your answer. This will help others and also get the question off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: It say I can accept my own answer in 2 days

Comment: I think your questions could look *much* better with only a little [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String manufacturer = "xiaomi";

```
 if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        //this will open auto start screen where user can enable 
             permission for your app
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new 
                ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", 
               "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

I used this code and now its working fine.